# run command inside of ${ curly braces

Tags: bash, shell, command, command-substitution

I want to alias `cd` so that it takes me to the root of my current git project, and if that can't be found it takes me to my normal home dir.

I am trying to set `HOME` to either the git root or, if that can't be found, my normal home variable.

```
alias cd='HOME="${$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel):-~}" cd'
```

It doesn't work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run a command inside `${}`, except in the fallback clause for when a value is not set (in POSIX sh or bash; might be feasible in zsh, which allows all manner of oddball syntax).

Regardless, far fewer contortions are needed if using a function:

```
# yes, you can call this cd, if you *really* want to.
cdr() {
   if (( $# )); then
     command cd "$@"
   else
     local home
     home=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null) || home=$HOME
     command cd "$home"
   fi
}
```

Note:

- Using a function lets us test our argument list, use branching logic, have local variables, &c.
- `command cd` is used to call through to the real `cd` implementation rather than recursing.

Comment: `command cd` vs `builtin cd`? I've been using `builtin` in every function I've written so far :/

Comment: Is it possible to hide the .. stderr i think ... of `$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)` because it errors if there are no git repos.

Comment: Of course; put a `2>/dev/null` inside the subshell.

Comment: `builtin cd` is perfectly fine.

Comment: `zsh`: `foo=${:-$(echo yup)}` :)

Comment: You could just do something like this: `cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null || echo $HOME)"`  Edit: added quotes.

Comment: @chepner, ...heh. I had a sneaking suspicion that I was missing something when I made that statement without any caveats, and there we have it. :)

Comment: @dramzy, indeed, though some additional quotes are called for to fix oddball directory names.

Comment: @dramzy, ...almost right, but you still want a separate pair of quotes around the `$HOME` too.

Comment: Why are those needed?

Comment: Consider `HOME=/nfs/why would you name it this       seriously?/me`.

Comment: That works with my `cd` command; unless I am missing some special character that's not showing properly here.

Comment: @dramzy, ...to make it *not* work, try a name with two consecutive spaces or a literal tab. `echo $HOME` will coalesce them into a single space. Or a `*` surrounded by spaces, which would be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory. Or, say, a directory named `hello [cruel] world` -- if you have a file or directory named `c`, `r`, `u`, `e` or `l`, in the current working directory, then the `[cruel]` will be replaced with that letter.

Comment: @dramzy, ...another case where `echo $HOME` will behave surprisingly is if `IFS` has a non-whitespace value. `IFS=/`, for instance, and it'll replace all the `/`s in the directory name with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it is possible to execute commands inside parameter expansions.
Well, only on the failure side, that is:

```
$ unset var
$ echo ${var:-"$(echo "hello world!")"}
```

So, you may get the git command executed if you use the failure side.
Assuming that var is empty:

```
unset var
var=${var:-"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)"}"
```

But that would be simpler with:

```
var="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)"
```

And, if var is still empty after that, use:

```
HOME=${var:-~} builtin cd
```

That yields:

```
var="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)"; HOME=${var:-~} builtin cd
```

Which may be used in an alias as :

```
alias cdr='var="$(git …)"; HOME=${var:-~} builtin cd'
```

Comment: This is the original answer I was looking for.

Comment: Clever. Bravo!!